# How to refresh Power Query using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I created a query in Power Query. What I need to do is to refresh PQ and save the Workbook upon running the macro. I've tried to do it using various macros but none of them refreshes a query. I use this macro in other Workbook - it opens given Workbook, 'refreshes' it (but it doesn't in fact because it lasts too short) and closes. Interesting thing is that when I run 'Refresh all' on Excel ribbon then PQ refreshes (all connections and quesries). However, when I use `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` then it doesn't refresh PQ at all.

Below is my macro with many ways of refreshing PQ:

```
Sub RefreshQuery()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    File = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MyFile.xlsx"
    Set MyWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(File)
   
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.FastCombine = True 'ignores privacy levels on all computers
    
    'Refresh option #1
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    'Refresh option #2
    For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        cn.Refresh
    Next cn

    'Refresh option #3
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("GetStatData").Refresh

    'Refresh option #4
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - GetStatData").Refresh

    'Refresh option #5
    ActiveWorkbook.Query("GetStatData").Refresh

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))   
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try replacing of `ActiveWorkbook` with `MyWorkBook`, in all cases where it appears.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, still no refreshing

Comment: Are the queries embedded in the macro'd workbook, or MyFile.xlsx ?

Comment: In MyFile.xlsx. 'Refresh' macro is located in other Workbook which serves as a global refresher, I refresh various Excel files from that global Workbook.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - GetStatData").Refresh` should work on the `GetStatData` query, although as @FaneDuru said - it's better to be specific about the workbook so use `MyWorkbook.Connections....`

Comment: Have you tried `MyWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheetname").ListObjects("tablename").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` ?

Comment: If you place a `Stop` command on this line `Set MyWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(File): Stop` and press `F5` (in VBE) when code stops, is the necessary refresh done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the following to refresh PowerQuery tables:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("<yourworksheetname>").ListObjects("<yourtablename>") _
    .QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be happening because you are referencing the active workbook.
in the macro above, if you have another workbook activated, it will not work, because you referencing the active workbook.
Try changing your code, activating the workbook where the queries are sitting in and then refresh.

Sub RefreshQuery()

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

File = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\MyFile.xlsx"
Set MyWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(File)

MyWorkBook.activate

MyWorkbook.Queries.FastCombine = True 'ignores privacy levels on all computers

'Refresh option #1
MyWorkbook.RefreshAll

MyWorkbook.Save
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")) '-> do you really need this?  
MyWorkbook.Close
```

End Sub

You must include a loop if there is more than one workbook.